# Where is `service status service-name` getting the log print outs from?

Tags: ssh, sysvinit

with `sudo service ssh status` we get an output of logs, such as

```
Jul 16 07:35:50 Linux sshd[1426235]: Disconnected from invalid user root 111.111.111.111 port 59242 [preauth]
Jul 16 07:38:50 Linux sshd[1429104]: User root not allowed because account is locked
```

I'm having a hard time understanding where this is from. My `sshd` config is set to log to `SysLogFacility AUTH`.

Is `service` just parsing the syslog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal is controlled by the systemd-journald daemon. It collects information from different sources and loads the messages into the journal.

The systemd journal is not a large text file. It’s a binary file maintained by the daemon. So, it can’t be opened with a text editor. the location and size of this binary file is controlled by the daemon’s configuration file. It doesn’t have to be persistent either; using configuration parameters, an administrator can turn off journaling altogether or keep it in memory so it’s volatile in nature. With in-memory journaling, systemd creates its journal files under the /run/log/journal directory. The directory is created if it doesn’t exist. With persistent storage, the journal is created under /var/log/journal directory; again, the directory is created by systemd if needed. If this directory is deleted for some reason, systemd-journald will not re-create it automatically; rather, it will write the logs under /run/log/journal in a non-persistent way. It will re-create the directory when the daemon is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, for future reference use `journalctl -u service-name` to see the log entries for a particular service.

Comment: Or `systemctl -l status service-name`